# Variable return as nil

Tags: variables, lua, return, null

I'm confused by this error.  I'm writing a lua script for mocp to display info in conky.  When I play music files in "/media/Stuff/old-music" everything works fine but I get an error when I play music files in "/home/tony/Music".  None of the directories are hard coded in my script.  The error says a variable is returned as nil.  I check and the music file has the required info.  Why am I getting this error?

error..

Conky: llua_do_call: function conky_main execution failed: /home/tony/.conky/lua-test/albumart.lua:68: attempt to concatenate global 'album' (a nil value)

code...

```
....
totaltime,totaltimesecs,song,artist,album,albumart=newsong(update_num)
....
function newsong()
    local f = io.popen("mocp -Q %album")
    album= f:read("*a")
    f:close()
    album=string.gsub(album,"[\n]","")
    local f = io.popen("mocp -Q %artist")
    artist= f:read("*a")
    f:close()
    artist=string.gsub(artist,"[\n]","")
    local f = io.popen("mocp -Q %song")
    song= f:read("*a")
    f:close()
    song=string.gsub(song,"[\n]","")
    local f = io.popen("mocp -Q %tt")
    totaltime= f:read("*a")
    f:close()
    totaltime=string.gsub(totaltime,"[\n]","")
    local f = io.popen("mocp -Q %ts")
    totaltimesecs= f:read("*a")
    f:close()
    totaltime=string.gsub(totaltime,"[\n]","")
return totaltime,totaltimesecs,song,artist,album,albumart
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written seems unrelated to the actual error code. The error code specifically describes this problem:

```
.../albumart.lua:68: attempt to concatenate global 'album' (a nil value)
```

This means that you are trying to concatenate the `album` variable using the concatenate operator `..`, and it's value happens to be nil.

The code you have written suggests that this should not be the case (even though you may want to try make all the variables in the function `local`). Please take a look at line 68 in your file to find the problem.

Comment: But why does it work fine with one directory and not the other?

Comment: What does `mocp -Q %album` return in the "not working" directory?

Comment: A friend figured it out for me.  I had one too many returns in the rest of the code. Rookie mistake. :/  Thanks for help.